# QWC2 | get feature/attribute in standalone mode to open URL?

Tags: qgis-server, qwc2

I have a QGIS project deployed to QGIS-Server and published/rendered by QWC2 in standalone modus (not by Docker). Some layers (arranged in groups) do have an attribute named URL with an full URL to reference pdf documents. Other layers do not have the URL attribute.

How can I configure the QWC2 theme (themesConfig.json) or other config files in the qwc2-app directory (copied from qwc2-demo-app) to get the attributes served from the QGIS-Server as wms and get the URL attribute to "compose" a clickable action to open the corresponding URL?

Unfortunately the QWC2 documentation is somewhat "cryptic" for someone new like me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it should be straight-forward:

> URLs in attribute text values with no HTML markup are automatically
> converted to an interactive hyperlink.

Otherwise, you can use HTML tag `<a>` in attribute value. I think it works without QWC services.

See [documentation](https://qwc-services.github.io/topics/FeatureInfo/#attribute-values-html-markup-hyperlinks-images)

Answer (score 0):

In my setup the issue about the attributes not served by WMS from QGIS Server to QWC2 (the QWC2 app in the browser was premitted not load attributes data in the background) was caused by an Cross-Origin request error (CORS) and the missing "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header statment towards the QGIS Server domain.

It is correct - in the feature info URLs in attributes are rendered as clickable links.

I am using now MapTips to show/render a quasi direct clickable link to the external PDF document (MapTip configured in the QGIS project on Layer Preferences > Display).